# how to stop functions in a disabled module from rewriting other functions in magento 2?

Tags: magento2

I'm using Magento 2.1.7 and have created a custom module to overwrite some tax/subtotal calculation functions through dependency injection. Now I was trying to stop my module to do an experiment, however, with my module disabled through admin interface, I found my functions were still working until I totally removed my module folder from magento directory.

Is there an easier way to disable not just the output of the module but also all functions in that module without having to remove the whole module folder?

Comment: i would not use the backend for this. use `bin/magento module:disable`

Comment: module:disable doesn't stop system from running functions in that module through dependency injection, as long as the code is there. What I was asking is whether we can truly disable module totally, i.e. any code in the module will not be functioning.

Comment: did you read the text that prompts after you call module:disable? setup:di:compile does the trick

Comment: No. it doesn't - I did setup:di:compile as well as setup:upgrade too, and neither of them fixes the problem, and based on document, module:disable only stops output of the module and does not stop dependency injection.